# Why is max_allowed_packet not having an effect?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put a large amount of data into a database.

I have observed that when the data is a lot greater than 1Mb, I get a 500 - Mysql has gone away error.

When the data is closer to the 1Mb mark, I get an error stating that the max packet size has been reached.

When the data is less than or equal to 1Mb, the query succeeds every time.

I have had a look max_allowed_packet in my.ini (I'm running on a Windows machine), and set it to 16M and even increased it higher. I have made sure that I have restarted mysql too.

But the same behavior is happening. Is there another setting somewhere that I am missing? For your information, I am using PHP to run the queries.

Thanks.

Comment: what type of mysql column is it?

Comment: are you sure it is a config, and not a problem with your code?

Comment: I am certain that it has nothing to do with the code. This problem is occuring in two different places, on the same database and server.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: Nope, still looking around. I will post the solution as soon as I find one.

Comment: Paste the code that executes the query so others can re-create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to change it in two places. I discovered on phpMyAdmin, under settings and variables that max packets allowed was indeed still 1M, despite me changing it in the config.

With this new information, I was able to focus my searches and it led me to

SET @@global.max_allowed_packet=n

Which showed me exactly how to change the global settings!

Problem is, I think if the server resets, it goes back to what it was, I need to do some settings file. More complications that I don't need right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the max_allowed_packet as a global variable.  You can set this variable dynamically, without restarting the MYSQL Service.

You can increase it up to 1 gigabyte.  I'd recommend setting it to at least 2x the largest data string you expect to insert.  That will give you some room to expand because of course next week you will have to handle a larger file than you expected.

See an example of setting the max_allowed_packet dynamically from PHP code here:  http://www.devplace.nl/blog/storing-large-values-in-mysql-fields-with-php

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and solved it by increasing **upload_max_filesize** and **memory_limit** on php.ini

Comment: I read the upload max filesize defaults to 2M. I can check, but I doubt its been shrunk

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` a file handle, and then bind the `resource` to the parameter.